# Changing the image on list after submitting jquery/ajax form

Tags: jquery, html, css, ajax

I have two problems:

I have listed files, and when i'm clicking on one of my files the form appears, and I can derscribe my image, after click on submit button my form changes into "added" info. But I want also change title on my list, I want i.e. to appear the YES string next to the list item, which I recently added description to. How to do it?

Second problem is about refreshing form, I don't want to see the added message, just some loading gif while it's computing the database request, and when it's complete I want to see the form filled with my recently added info. How to do it?

**Jsfiddle to illustrate my recent version of the script to correct**: http://jsfiddle.net/GSC3x/5/

**@@UPDATE TO FIRST PROBLEM:**

When I have a list item like this:

```
<li class="files"><a href="#" class="show_hide" >filename <img align="right" src="http://artivia-dev2/git.png" alt="OK" /></a>
```

And when i want to change only the image here after submit the form - how to do it?

Comment: Can you provide more details of your problem?

Comment: What kind of details, didn't I provide enough info?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
upform.html("<div class='message'></div>");
```

so after you get response you are replacing the content of div with another content. 
So the initial form that you had is lost now, Instead of this send json response from your server and fill your form with server values.

To append Yes to the li like file1 Yes

sample HTML

```
<li><a href="#" class="show_hide" >file2</a><span></span>
```

sample code

```
jQuery(upform).parent().prev().text('Yes');
```

Comment: How to replace the file2 name into something different? Not just adding?

Comment: do you mean to say instead of file2 make it file5 ?

Comment: for example - can be that : ] when i'm adding span at the and of the list item, form doesnt appear after click on it.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/GSC3x/9/), is this what you want ?

Comment: That's exactly my point - thanks :) Could you just tell me, according to my first problem, when I'm sending the form into some php file, it fills my database with info - the jquery has variables with info I sent, why can't I just fill the form with these variables instead of sending a json request from server?

Comment: @pawel check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mprabhat/GSC3x/13/), there is some change in html and javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following code into your button click event.

```
var aLink = $(this).parents('li').children(':first');
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GSC3x/10/

Comment: Thank you for your attention, could you please check the update in my first post?

Comment: you simply grab the image and change its SRC. `$(this).parents('li').children(':first').children('img').attr('src', 'new-url-goes-here');`